# Aternative diode classes for high frequency(10GHz) applications

Tags: diodes, high-frequency, high-speed, diode-clamp

I'm trying to design a voltage clamping circuit for a 10GHz signal. I've modeled it in spice using several schottky diodes and it works but only when the signal pulse is at least a few nanoseconds long. In my case I need diodes that can handle a pulse in the 50 picosecond range which means the reverse recovery time needs to be in the single digit picosecond range(The application can handle quite a bit of distortion to the signal) Unfortunately, this key timing requirement seems to be missing off of most data sheets that I look at for diodes. Does anyone know where I can find diodes in this range?

**EDIT**:Not sure why this was put on hold. I did not ask about a "specific product" as the hold reason states, I was asking about diodes in general. You might be thinking this is a minor distinction, but if you read, the details of the close rule and the reason it was created, you can see that it violates neither the technical definition of the rule nor the intent of the rule. Furthermore the intent of the rule is to prevent questions which are not likely to be helpful to others in the future, and this is a problem which is likely to be encountered by those working on increasingly high frequency circuits. The recommendation to move to microwave components is a spot-on answer to the question which is not overly specific at all. Even furthermore, the recommended "fix" for the close rule is to "Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve." Which I have done to the best of my ability. I've explained why the typical diodes are not sufficient to meet my needs and explained that the specifications on data sheets were missing the information that I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diodes for 10 GHz are very much in the "microwave" part of electronics, you will probably not find any suitable diodes at Farnell, Digikey etc.

You might have a better chance at "microwave" companies like Skyworks, Tryquint, Avago and Minicircuits.

To get you going [this article](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/200826A.pdf) might be interesting.

I am unsure if you will find any discrete diode for your application, in the microwave world it is usually integrated in some small metal box. This is because you need properly matched transmission lines to the diodes.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a place to start looking, the microwave diodes seem to have better documentation all around and are definitely more geared towards my application

Comment: Happy I could help :-)